# aspnet membership for zend php

Tags: php

I have multiple web application some of use asp.NET and other Zend PHP and for .NET application i used aspnet membership framework, now i need to make single login for all my application so how can i do that? can PHP use the aspnet membership database? if yes how can i integrate the aspnet membership on php?

My primary requirements is single loging screen for all web application.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at PEAR's [Auth](http://pear.php.net/package/Auth) and [LiveUser](http://pear.php.net/package/LiveUser) package and configure them to use your existing database.

Answer (score 0):

An aspnet membership database is a regular SQL Server data base and you can access it with PHP.

look at the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php