# PHP under ASP.NET MVC security

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I want to do this same as mentioned here [aspnet membership for zend php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062470/aspnet-membership-for-zend-php) but, the ASP.NET should be the main credential controler - not PHP.

My scenario is that we have already developed ASP.NET MVC CRM and now want to add file explorer. We choosen http://www.ajaxplorer.info/, but it is PHP application. So there is a security issue: Some could get access to the files without singing in. How to prevent this?

Or maybe you know asp mvc file manager? We know IZWebFileManager and Telerik FileManager, but they have to poor funcionality.

Comment: can't you simple create your own Membership and Roles for the PHP application instead of the default one? you have access to the code, so you could try that, no?

Comment: Yes, but our app is written in ASP.NET MVC, so we can share user session with PHP by databse. But this will have bad impact on performance.

Whats more I'm afraid of security issues created in PHP working as separate app. That's why I want it to work under 'ASP.NET umbrella'.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative file manager that works with asp.net is [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/)